# What is the proper way of adding trust certificates to confluent kafka connect docker image

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I have a kafka connect cluster ([cp_kafka_connect_base](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base)) on docker, and I need to include a `.pem` file in order to connect to a source over TLS. It seems there are already a number of trusted certificates included in connect, so how would I add a new trusted certificate without invalidating the old ones?

#### Specific problem

I want to use [MongoDB Source Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/v1.6/), alongside a number of other connectors. As per [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/v1.6/security-and-authentication/tls-and-x509/), I have imported my `.pem` certificate in a `.jks` store, and added the following envvars to my kafka connect containers:

> KAFKA_OPTS="
> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=*mystore.jks* 
> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=*mypass*

This lets me connect to my data source, but invalidates other TLS connections, unless I add them all to my `.jks`. Since all other TLS connections work out of the box, I shouldn't need to manually import every single one of them to a `.jks`, just to make one connector implementation happy.

I have also tried setting:

> CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE: "PEM"
> CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: "*myloc*"

but the truststore location config isn't known, and TLS doesn't work:

> WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:384)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am facing similar issue

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am facing similar issue

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am facing similar issue